# Index column in SELECT EXCEPT() after joining table using default table name as prefix

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This question is following up from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942891/rename-all-column-names-for-joining-purpose-in-big-query/49945157?noredirect=1#comment86986581_49945157) originally regarding renaming the column names with table names as prefixes in google big query. 
Long story short, I need to join two tables with exact names and keep the origins of the columns.

I learned that I can use, for example:

```
SELECT table_A , table_B
FROM table_A
FULL JOIN table_B
USING (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3)
```

This code would generate a joined table with column names for example: `table_A.KEY1`, `table_B.KEY1` in the result on google big query.

However I have trouble to deselect some of the columns from the joined table. For example,

```
WITH merged AS (
    SELECT table_A , table_B
    FROM table_A
    FULL JOIN table_B
    USING (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3)
)

SELECT * EXCEPT(table_A.KEY1, table_B.KEY1)
FROM merged
```

I got this error

> Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "."

Does anybody have any good idea how to circumvent this issue? Thank you in advance!

This manipulation is out of the purpose of reshaping long table into wide table. 
For example, I have a long table

```
KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 VALUE1 VALUE2 DOC_TYPE
1     2     3   A      Q     PAY
1     2     3   A      Q     INVOICE
2     3     4   D      B     PAY
2     3     4   D      B     INVOICE
```

and ideally reshape into the wide table using KEY1 KEY2 KEY3:

```
KEY1 KEY2 KEY3 VALUE1.pay VALUE2.pay VALUE1.inv VALUE2.inv 
1     2     3   A         Q          A          Q   
2     3     4   D         B          D          B
```

Since the table contains many columns. It is impractical to rename all of them manually. I wonder if Google big query can have some shortcut to do it.

Comment: what the practical reason for this? asking not just out of curiosity but to find proper solution for you ... in your original question you mentioned that yo have 100+ columns in those tables - so what would be real use-case for removing just one column?

Comment: Thank you! So the idea is to change a long table to a wide table then applying the filtering algorithm on the wide table. I'll write more details in the question.

Comment: and my understanding that 3 keys are just example and in reality you have 100s ? right? so you do not want to do it manually as if you would did if it were just three keys? right?

Comment: There are 4 keys, but the Value columns are 100 +. The idea is to move the Value columns to the side using the 4 keys to make sure I don't mismatch the rows. There are only two types of docs in the table. So I thought if I just split into two tables and merge them, it would be easier in the BQ SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and I am re-using naming from your original [question and respective answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49945157/5221944) so to preserve context)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  key1, key2, key3, key4, 
  (SELECT AS STRUCT inv.* EXCEPT(key1, key2, key3, key4)) inv, 
  (SELECT AS STRUCT prof.* EXCEPT(key1, key2, key3, key4)) prof
FROM inv FULL JOIN prof
USING (key1, key2, key3, key4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH merged AS (
    SELECT table_A , table_B
    FROM table_A
    FULL JOIN table_B
    USING (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3)
)

SELECT
  (SELECT AS STRUCT table_A.* EXCEPT(KEY1)) AS table_A,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT table_B.* EXCEPT(KEY1)) AS table_B
FROM merged
```